# How to retrieve a line as a list instead of a string?

Tags: string, list, functional-programming, clojure, text-files

I'm a newbie using the Clojure language, but I got really stuck with the following problem working with text files. Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

I have a file (backend.txt) that contains a matrix:

```
((A 10 "Ciel" 10)
(B 15 "Sprite" 10)
(C 20 "Coca-Cola" 10)
(D 12 "Fuze-Tea" 10)
(E 50 "Hattori-Sake" 10)
(F 40 "02Linn-Soju" 10)
(G 16 "Fanta" 10)
(H 25 "Canada-Dry" 10)
(A12 54 "Cigarros" 10)
(Kiero 78 "Calculadora" 10))
```

I also have the following "locate" function:

```
(defn locate [token filename]
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
  (let [line-no (atom 0)
        result (filter #(.contains % token)
                       (line-seq rdr))]
    (if result
      (-> result first)
      nil))))
```

Basically, the "locate" function takes two arguments, a token and a filename, and returns the first line in the file that contains the token.

```
(locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt")
> (A12 54 "Cigarros" 10)
```

The outcome of **`(locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt")`** is a **string**:

```
(string? (locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt")
>true
```

I convert it into a seq by using the "read-string" method.

```
(read-string (locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt"))
>(A12 54 Cigarros 10)
```

```
(seq? (read-string (locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt")))
>true
```

However, notice that `Cigarros` no longer has the double quotes, and it's really critical that those double quotes remain because by removing them it messes with other functions in my script. So how can I preserve them?

What I expect is to convert the string from the outcome of `(locate "Cigarros" "backend.txt")`  to a list like this:

```
(A12 54 "Cigarros" 10)
;; (seq? (A12 54 "Cigarros" 10))
;; > true
```

I hope I made myself clear, and not sounding confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotes should be there - in other words, `Cigarros` should still be a string. It's just that whatever you're using as your REPL doesn't print them.

Here's how it looks on my end:

```clj
(def s "(A12 54 \"Cigarros\" 10)")
=> #'dev/s
(read-string s)
=> (A12 54 "Cigarros" 10)
```

You can validate that you have a string there by executing `(string? (nth (read-string s) 2))`.

Also note that a better approach might be to read the file as a proper EDN data structure and *then* filter it.